# Is there a way to get answers to questions asked to prospective new members of a Facebook group?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

From the internet search it seems to me that there is no way to get programmatically the 3 answers  questions asked to prospective new members of a Facebook group.

So far I found that I am able to see the answers only when I see awaiting requests to join a group.

It might good enough to capture the answers. But how?

Comment: Please look at this [Group Collectro](https://groupcollector.com). This will help you to find group member answers.

Comment: According to this [thread](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=378716609590113) it does not seem to be a thing yet, group's [api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/) does not seem to provide an endpoint for it either

Comment: @InsertCheesyLine, well I thought someone could come with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Facebook - This is currently not an option
refer - [FB Community Link](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=2042227765852802)

Alternatively, You Can Use Group Collector To Collect New Facebook Group Member Answers, Including Their Email And Save Them Into Google Sheet And Your Favorite Email Marketing Software Without Zapier.

Go to https://groupcollector.com/

You can also set up Group Collector Auto Approval, which allows you to auto-approve new group members after certain intervals that meet your specific criteria.

There are also other Chrome extensions to Capture the answers and store them in Excel Sheets.

Check

- [Extract Facebook Group Answers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extract-facebook-group-an/dfcmfhebmcphgldfbejjflnojabpemoi?hl=en-GB)
- [Group Answers Collector For FB](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmac-%E2%80%94-group-answers-coll/omefdeapnicniondiefejngddkjikegn)